# `NullPoinerException` on an `@Autowired` dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is my first `Spring` Application so please forgive my ignorance on the matter.

I'm getting a `NullPoinerException` on an `@Autowired` dependency.

```
14:08:48,415 SEVERE [com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler] (default task-4) : java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.letifer.ui.factory.BudgetTabbedPaneFactory$BudgetTabbedPane.init(BudgetTabbedPaneFactory.java:26)
at com.letifer.ui.factory.BudgetTabbedPaneFactory.createComponent(BudgetTabbedPaneFactory.java:44)
at com.letifer.ui.commons.BudgetMainUI.init(BudgetMainUI.java:44)
```

**BudgetTabbedPaneFactory.java:**

```
package com.letifer.ui.factory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.letifer.utils.constants.BudgetStringConstants;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Component;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@SpringComponent
public class BudgetTabbedPaneFactory implements BudgetComponent {

    private class BudgetTabbedPane extends VerticalLayout {

        private TabSheet tabSheet;

        @Autowired
        BudgetAccountsFactory accountsFactory;

        Component accounts;

        public BudgetTabbedPane init() {
            tabSheet = new TabSheet();
            accounts = accountsFactory.createComponent(); // <-- NullPoinerException
            return this;
        }

        public BudgetTabbedPane layout() {
            setSizeFull();
            tabSheet.addTab(accounts, BudgetStringConstants.ACCOUNTS_TAB_NAME.getName());
            tabSheet.addTab(new Label(BudgetStringConstants.BALANCE_TAB_NAME.getName()), BudgetStringConstants.BALANCE_TAB_NAME.getName());
            tabSheet.addTab(new Label(BudgetStringConstants.STATISTICS_TAB_NAME.getName()), BudgetStringConstants.STATISTICS_TAB_NAME.getName());

            addComponent(tabSheet);

            return this;
        }

    }

    public Component createComponent() {
        return new BudgetTabbedPane().init().layout();
    }

}
```

this class has a `BudgetAccountsFactory` dependency

**BudgetAccountsFactory.java:**

```
package com.letifer.ui.factory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Alignment;
import com.vaadin.ui.Component;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;

@SpringComponent
public class BudgetAccountsFactory implements BudgetComponent {

    @Autowired
    private BudgetAccountMenuFactory accountMenuFactory;

    @Autowired
    private BudgetInfoPaneFactory infoPaneFactory;

    private class BudgetAccountsLayout extends HorizontalLayout {

        Component menu;
        Component infoPane;

        public BudgetAccountsLayout init() {

            menu = accountMenuFactory.createComponent();
            infoPane = infoPaneFactory.createComponent();

            return this;
        }

        public BudgetAccountsLayout layout() {

            setMargin(true);
            setSizeFull();

            addComponent(menu);
            setComponentAlignment(menu, Alignment.TOP_LEFT);
            setExpandRatio(menu, 1);

            addComponent(infoPane);
            setComponentAlignment(infoPane, Alignment.TOP_LEFT);
            setExpandRatio(infoPane, 2);

            return this;
        }

    }

    public Component createComponent() {
        return new BudgetAccountsLayout().init().layout();
    }

}
```

this class has another 2 dependecies, `BudgetAccountMenuFactory` and `BudgetInfoPaneFactory`

**BudgetAccountMenuFactory.java:**

```
package com.letifer.ui.factory;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import com.letifer.utils.constants.BudgetStringConstants;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Component;
import com.vaadin.ui.ListSelect;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@SpringComponent
public class BudgetAccountMenuFactory implements BudgetComponent {

    private class BudgetAccountMenuLayout extends VerticalLayout {

        private ListSelect<String> options;

        public BudgetAccountMenuLayout init() {
            options = new ListSelect<String>(BudgetStringConstants.ACCOUNTS_MENU_OPTION_TITLE.getName());
            List<String> optionsList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(BudgetStringConstants.ACCOUNTS_MENU_OPTION_SHOW_ACCOUNTS.getName(),
                    BudgetStringConstants.ACCOUNTS_MENU_OPTION_ADD.getName(), BudgetStringConstants.ACCOUNTS_MENU_OPTION_REMOVE.getName()));
            Set<String> optionsSet = new HashSet<String>(optionsList);
            options.setValue(optionsSet);
            return this;
        }

        public BudgetAccountMenuLayout layout() {
            setMargin(true);
            setSizeFull();

            addComponent(options);
            return this;
        }

    }

    public Component createComponent() {
        return new BudgetAccountMenuLayout().init().layout();
    }

}
```

**BudgetInfoPaneFactory.java:**

```
package com.letifer.ui.factory;

import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Component;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@SpringComponent
public class BudgetInfoPaneFactory implements BudgetComponent {

    private class BudgetInfoPaneLayout extends VerticalLayout {

        public static final String VIEW_NAME = "info";

        private Label label;

        public BudgetInfoPaneLayout init() {
            label = new Label("INFO HERE");
            return this;
        }

        public BudgetInfoPaneLayout layout() {
            setMargin(true);
            setSizeFull();
            addComponent(label);
            return this;
        }

    }

    public Component createComponent() {
        return new BudgetInfoPaneLayout().init().layout();
    }

}
```

My ignorance led me to believe that "nested" dependencies(an `@Autowired` component within an `@Autowired` component) will work just fine.

But obviously I get a `NullPoinerException` on the top component.

**What am I missing here?**

**And what is the Intelligent way of "injecting a dependency within a dependency"?**

Comment: When you create an object with `new` like you do here `new BudgetInfoPaneLayout()` then that object will not have any Spring managed content like injected objects and properties - they will be null. Instead of creating objects with new, just inject them into the classes.

Comment: @csm_dev this should be an answer to the question :)

Comment: @csm_dev My assumption was that I don't need it to be managed by `Spring` since its an inner class, and other dependencies using the same `builder-pattern` but without "nested dependencies" are injected without any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think we need to clarify what is dependency injection in Spring.

1. When you mark class with annotation `@SpringComponent`, `@Controller`, `@Repository` etc spring automatically creates instance of this class. But this will be not `BudgetTabbedPaneFactory` but dynamically generated subclass of `BudgetTabbedPaneFactory` (so called [Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)).
2. After instantiating all annotated components are visible for Spring. They are in `Spring context` and become `managed beans`.
3. Then Spring checks all methods and fields marked with `@Autowired` and tries to initialize them with appropriate instance of automatically created object from previous stage.

But when you create object manually it will exist outside the `Spring context` and Spring will not care about it and its annotations. It actually don't know about your class at all. [Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) are just a sort of markers they doesn't perform any functionality by themselves.

Read section about [Spring IoC container](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html). Maybe it will help to find best solution for your task.

P.S. For your situation your should at least put `@SpringComponent` annotation over `BudgetTabbedPane` (not sure if it works for inner classes), because now it is not Spring bean and do not create it manually to let Spring inject dependencies for your.

Comment: Well annotating the inner classes and injecting them solved the problem...
I understand the consept, but there are still `new` type creation of components in the code li `new VerticalLayout()` and it works, and i cant understand why?

Comment: Because that class does not have any spring managed components inside of it.

Comment: Yes, @csm_dev is right. In other words if you have some Spring annotation inside your class (`@Autowired`, `@SpringComponent`) it have to be instantiated by Spring.  Try add some `@Autowired` property to `BudgetAccountMenuLayout` or `BudgetInfoPaneLayout` and access to it in `init()`. You will also get `NullPointerException`.